# invalid argument: no armored data found

Tags: go, cryptography, openpgp

When I try to load an armored GPG public key to verify a signature, I get the error `openpgp: invalid argument: no armored data found`

My code (some data shortened to fit better):

```
pubKey := `-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
xsFNBF/9Xn [...] =Yo8+
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----`

content := "Hello World"

signature := `-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
wsFcBAE [...] =z3nL
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----`

keyring, err := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(strings.NewReader(pubKey))
if err != nil {
    // Errors out here with: openpgp: invalid argument: no armored data found
    // ...
}

// Code never gets this far but I'm including this in case I'm using it all wrong...
_, err = openpgp.CheckArmoredDetachedSignature(keyring, strings.NewReader(content), strings.NewReader(signature))
if err != nil {
    return false, err
}
```

[Entire public key](https://pastebin.com/r5Fwku1t), [entire signature](https://pastebin.com/jiwcndnA).

Answer (score 1):

edit: i think its something to do with your public key armor not being valid. below is a link to a working function with an example `const e2ePublicKey` [public key](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/eec23a3978adcfd26c29f4153eaa3e3d9b2cc53a/openpgp/read_test.go#L558).

instead of using `strings.NewReader(pubKey)`, they use:

`keyring, err := openpgp.ReadArmoredKeyRing(bytes.NewBufferString(pubKey))`

maybe another `bytes.NewBufferString` for the signature.

(from [src](https://github.com/golang/crypto/blob/eec23a3978adcfd26c29f4153eaa3e3d9b2cc53a/openpgp/read_test.go#L392))